# Is this a bug of NSum?

Tags: numerics, summation

Check this:

```
NSum[Log[Abs[m]],{m,1,24}]  
(*54.7847*)
NSum[Log[Abs[m]],{m,1,25}]
```

> NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) (Abs^[Prime])[m]/Abs[m] is not numerical at point m = 16. >>

I know that I can get around this issue by replacing `NSum` to `N@Sum` or even drop `Abs`. Yet I really want to know where is the `(Abs^\[Prime])[m]` comming from?

I haven't check this on all platforms, but at least this happens to `v10.1` (both Windows and Linux)& `v10.2(Windows)` even in `v7(Windows)`.  I must say I'm really shocked by such a stupid bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might it have something to with the option `NSumTerms`? From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSum.html):

> `NSumTerms` is the number of terms to use before extrapolation.
>
> By default NSum uses 15 terms at the beginning before approximating
>   the tail.

Thus trying it with just 16 terms instead of the default removes the error message.

```
NSum[Log[Abs[m]], {m, 1, 25}, NSumTerms -> 16]
(* 58.0036 *)

(* For verification *)
N@Sum[Log[Abs[m]], {m, 1, 25}]
(* 58.0036 *)
```

Comment: Possible. However, check this `NSum[Log[Abs[m]], {m, 1, 100}, NSumTerms -> 16]`, there are still error message. What I really want to know is why `(Abs^\[Prime])[m]` show up?

Comment: @luyuwuli so increase `NSumTerms` to 100 in that example and the error message disappears - where's the problem there? I can only guess that `(Abs^\[Prime])[m]` shows up because of the extrapolation...

Comment: +1, tempted to close vote - this is pretty well outlined in docs, though perhaps why some things wonkify the approximation process might be opaque.

Comment: I can somehow guess the issue out. The term comes from the consequence that the bulit in algorithm calculates the derivative in order to check the convergence, but it doesn't take into account that sometimes the derivative doesn't exist for non-analytic function. (in this case, `Abs`)

Comment: @blochwave  I'm think that the `NSum` should have take into account the non-analytic function. Otherwise it's really frustrating when this term show up in a huge expression.

Comment: @ luyuwuli Not nice of MMA. But try replacing Abs[x] -> Sqrt[x^2] which is completely equivalent for real m. Example: no problems with NSum[Log[Sqrt[m^2]], {m, 1, 100}]. The derivative of Sqrt[x^2] is similarly non-analytic.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Excellent idea! You help me again:) BTW, I figure it out the subtleties of my last multi-dimensional principal value integration . I'll update my post after finish my work.

Comment: @luyuwuli, since `NSum[]` uses Euler-Maclaurin summation as its default, and since that method involves taking the derivative of the summand, you get what you observe. As noted, it's better here to use `Sum[]` instead, possibly using the setting `Method -> "Procedural"` to do straightforward summation.