# Error "Summand (or its derivative)...is not numerical at point m = -85." on a simple sum

Tags: numerics, summation

I'm a beginner on mathematica..
I'm trying to calculate a simple sum of a function,

```
F1[n_]:=NSum[(V^2*8)/d^2*(I*ω[m]-I*Sign[ω[m]]*Sqrt[(ω[m])^2 +
  (d/2)^2])*1/(I*ω[m]+I*ν[n]-Σf), {m, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Where:

```
ω[n_] := ((2*n + 1)*π)/β
ν[n_] := (2*n*π)/β
d=12
V=0.25
Σf = 1 + I
β=1
```

For n=2, for example. But when I try to do this it returns an error message:

> "Summand (or its derivative)...is not numerical at point m = 15 "

But when I choose upper and lower bound of simulation with the function:

```
F2[n_, min_, max_] :=NSum[(V^2*8)/d^2*(I*ω[m] - 
  I*Sign[ω[m]]*Sqrt[(ω[m])^2 + (d/2)^2])*1/(I*ω[m] + I*ν[n] - Σf), {m, min, max}]
```

*Mathematica* returns a value for small limits, for example:

> F2[2, -10, 10] = 0.000757504 - 0.00143062 I

But, for:
`F2[2, -100, 100]` I have a similar error mensage.

> "Summand (or its derivative)...is not numerical at point m = -85."

I will be grateful if someone help-me on this calculations of infinity sum.

Comment: First, you have mismatched parenthesis somewhere. Second, your function \[Nu][n] needs a definition.

Comment: I Forgot,
\[Nu][n_] := (2*n*\[Pi])
And the parentesis is of \[omega] that i mismatched. But the problem persist

Comment: Is Beta defined?

Comment: Yes, Sorry,
I Choose \[Beta]=1

Comment: with V=1/4; F1[n_]:=NSum[Simplify[V^2* 8/d^2* (I* ω[m]-I* Sign[ω[m]]* Sqrt[ω[m]^2+(d/2)^2])* 1/(I* ω[m]+I* ν[n]-Σf)], {m,-Infinity, Infinity}]; F1[2] it quickly concludes ComplexInfinity

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the method of summation:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

β = 1;
d = 12;
V = 1/4;
Σf = 1 + I;
ω[m_] := ((2*m + 1)*π)
ν[n_] := (2*n*π)/β

F1[n_] := 
 NSum[(V^2*8)/
    d^2*(I*ω[m] - 
     I*Sign[ω[m]]*
      Sqrt[(ω[m])^2 + (d/2)^2])*1/(I*ω[m] + 
      I*ν[n] - Σf), {m, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Method -> "WynnEpsilon", WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

> 0.0004521 - 0.0014314 I

Or increasing `NSumTerms`:

```
F2[n_, min_, max_] := 
 NSum[(V^2*8)/
    d^2*(I*ω[m] - 
     I*Sign[ω[m]]*
      Sqrt[(ω[m])^2 + (d/2)^2])*1/(I*ω[m] + 
      I*ν[n] - Σf), {m, min, max}, 
  NSumTerms -> 200000]

F2[2, -100000, 100000]
```

> 0.000450002 - 0.00143142 I

This post was helpful:
[Is this a bug of NSum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94359/is-this-a-bug-of-nsum)

> Since NSum[] uses Euler-Maclaurin summation as its default, and since that method involves taking the derivative of the summand, you get what you observe. -J.M.

Comment: Now everything is working.
In fact there is a problem with derivatives on this function.
I'm in debit with you