# Error with NSum : it returns NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) f[n] is not numerical at point n=17

Tags: numerics, summation

Consider the following example (I had a lot of trouble to find a minimal working example, I think it is compactified enough now).

```
Omega0 = 1.
t=2
nAvg = 10.

Omegan[n_] := Omega0*Sqrt[n + 1]

f[n_] := Piecewise[{{Cos[Omegan[n]*t/2]^2*
     Abs[Exp[-nAvg/2]*Sqrt[nAvg]^n/Sqrt[Factorial[n]]], 
    0 <= n <= 20}}, 0]

NSum[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]
```

If you run this short script, it should return you :

> NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) [...] big message [...] is not 
>   numerical at point n = 16

This problem I am facing occurs only with some specific function. It occurs with this complicated looking function I gave you but if you try simpler one the script may just work correctly.

---

**My questions :**

First: I would like to understand **why** I have this error.

Second: How to solve it ?

**Extra question**

Is it really more efficient to use NSum[] than N[Sum[]]. Because I have read (I don't remember where) that when Mathematica sees N[Sum[]] he understands that the sum has to be done numerically (instead of trying symbolic method THEN approximating numerically).

---

**Extra infos :**

I have already seen [Is this a bug of NSum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94359/is-this-a-bug-of-nsum)

With some functions it solves the problem to add NSumTerms->number, with some other it doesn't. The thing is I would like to be able to face this problem "in general" so for this I need to understand what is happening (I read the documentation and I don't).

In short : how to do numeric summation in general with mathematica ? In my specific case I have functions that may be piecewise defined. In all generality my function can be a product/sum of piecewise functions so it is not obvious at first view to know the boundary of the sum without looking more carefully, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: There’s a t in the definition of f that has no numerical value given above.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes sorry I forgot to copy the line I defined t. Put t=2 and you will have the same problem

Comment: Better to use is: `N[Sum[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]]` or `Total@Table[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I use NSum for performance purposes. It is said that if I want to do numeric summation this function must be used for greater execution speed. And for my more specific problem I will have a lot of sum to evaluate, so I need to have an optimised version. Also I would like to understand what is the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I explored the meaning of the error message:

```
NSum[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]
```

> NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) [Piecewise]    <<1>> is not numerical at point n = 16.

The error message suggests evaluating `f` and its derivative at `16`:

```
f[16]
f'[16]
(*
  0.0454989
  -0.0802852 + 0.0523825 Derivative[1][Re][16]
*)
```

Aha! The derivative of `f` has a `Re'[16]` in it?  It must come from some nonanalytic complex function.  The only one in the definition of `f[]` is `Abs[]`.  Let's try the relatively new `RealAbs[]` in its place.

```
f[n_] := Piecewise[{{Cos[Omegan[n]*t/2]^2*
     RealAbs[Exp[-nAvg/2]*Sqrt[nAvg]^n/Sqrt[Factorial[n]]], 
    0 <= n <= 20}}, 0]

NSum[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]
(*  2.69803  *)
```

Success!

---

*Reply to comments:*

Most methods of `Sum[]` seek a symbolic solution. The methods of `NSum` use numerical methods to predict the sum without adding up all the terms. Such numerical methods are slower than adding up a small number of terms (less than, say, 10^5 or so depending on the summand). They also tend to rely on the summand being analytic (representable by power series), so `NSum` seems ill-suited for `Piecewise[]` summands whose support is bounded by a small interval.

`Sum[]` with `Method -> "Procedural"` simply adds up all the terms. It is similar to `Total@Table[N@f[n], {n, 1, 100}]` in both method and speed. (First suggested by [@Mariusz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200897/error-with-nsum-it-returns-nsumnsnum-summand-or-its-derivative-fn-is-no/200900?noredirect=1#comment519536_200897).)

Examples: The summands `Piecewise[{{(-1.)^n/n, n < 70}}, 0.]` produces a `Real` number in all cases; `Piecewise[{{(-1)^n/n, n < 70}}]` produces an `Integer` when `n >= 70` and otherwise either a `Real` in `NSum[]` because it is numericized or a `Rational` number normally.  `NSum[]` uses extrapolation to get `-Log[2.]`, which is incorrect but only by a little; however if we shorten the domain to `n < 60`, the sum is unacceptable.  One can inspect the difference in timings for oneself.

```
nn = 10^6;
summand = Piecewise[{{(-1)^n/N@n, n < 70}}];
nres = NSum[summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[N@summand, {n, nn}, Method -> "Procedural"] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@Table[N@summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.126167, -0.693147}
{0.016046, -0.700341}
{0.019534, -0.700341}
*)

nn = 10^6;
summand = Piecewise[{{(-1)^n/n, n < 70}}, 0.];
nres = NSum[summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[N@summand, {n, nn}, Method -> "Procedural"] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@Table[N@summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.015743, -0.693147}
{0.015114, -0.700341}
{0.016413, -0.700341}
*)

nn = 10^7;
summand = Piecewise[{{(-1)^n/n, n < 70}}, 0.];
nres = NSum[summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[N@summand, {n, nn}, Method -> "Procedural"] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@Table[N@summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.015895, -0.693147}
{0.149556, -0.700341}
{0.168185, -0.700341}
*)

nn = 10^7;
summand = Piecewise[{{(-1)^n/n, n < 60}}, 0.];
nres = NSum[summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[N@summand, {n, nn}, Method -> "Procedural"] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@Table[N@summand, {n, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.167812, -0.693175 - 0.00530469 I}
{0.14409, -0.70155}
{0.16297, -0.70155}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand, the summation method needs to compute derivative which is not possible for the complex function Abs(z) as it is not analytic. So either I change the function, either I change the method of summation. Is that correct ? Also, Is it indeed faster for numeric computation to use NSum[] rather than N[Sum[]] ?

Comment: I’d think NSum[] is faster than N[Sum[]] in this case. Sum[] will attempt a symbolic solution and probably fail; then NSum[] would be called. I think Mariusz’s 2nd approach is probably the fastest if the sums are finite and don’t have many terms. But it depends on the actual function

Comment: Thanks. However I dont think that when Sum fails for symbolic he calls NSum because in this example N[Sum[]] worked without the solution you proposed. Or if NSum is called it would be with a different method than the default one.

Comment: In your example in the OP, `Sum[]` does not fail. `NSum[]` would be called only if `Sum[]` fails to produce a number. In your example, it is doing the same thing as `Total@Table[f[n], {n, 1, 100}]` (but it does not seem to be calling those functions). It does this if the number of terms is finite and less than `SystemOptions["SymbolicSumThreshold"]`.

Comment: Oh ok. So when you meant when N[Sum[]] fails it doesn't mean just "fail to find symbolic expression", but more generally : fails to do the calculation (numercially or symbolically) which would be the case if too many numbers are involved for example. Thanks !

Comment: @StarBucK Yes. (Note when I wrote "Sum[] will...probably fail," that was a guess which was wrong (I was away from a computer and couldn't check).  See also my update.